# Bug when using TensorFlow-GPU + Python multiprocessing?

Tags: python, multithreading, tensorflow, multiprocessing

I have noticed a strange behavior when I use TensorFlow-GPU + Python multiprocessing.

I have implemented a [DCGAN](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06434) with some customizations and my own dataset. Since I am conditioning the DCGAN to certain features, I have training data and also test data for evaluation.

Due to the size of my datasets, I have written data loaders that run concurrently and preload into a queue using Python's [multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/multiprocessing.html).

The structure of the code roughly looks like this:

```
class ConcurrentLoader:
    def __init__(self, dataset):
        ...

class DCGAN
     ...

net = DCGAN()
training_data = ConcurrentLoader(path_to_training_data)
test_data = ConcurrentLoader(path_to_test_data)
```

This code runs fine on TensorFlow-CPU *and* on TensorFlow-GPU <= 1.3.0 using CUDA 8.0, but when I run the exact same code with **TensorFlow-GPU 1.4.1 and CUDA 9** (latest releases of TF & CUDA as of Dec 2017) it crashes:

```
2017-12-20 01:15:39.524761: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-12-20 01:15:39.527795: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-12-20 01:15:39.529548: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
2017-12-20 01:15:39.535341: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:385] could not create cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR
2017-12-20 01:15:39.535383: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_dnn.cc:352] could not destroy cudnn handle: CUDNN_STATUS_BAD_PARAM
2017-12-20 01:15:39.535397: F tensorflow/core/kernels/conv_ops.cc:667] Check failed: stream->parent()->GetConvolveAlgorithms( conv_parameters.ShouldIncludeWinogradNonfusedAlgo<T>(), &algorithms) 
[1]    32299 abort (core dumped)  python dcgan.py --mode train --save_path ~/tf_run_dir/test --epochs 1
```

What really confuses me is that if I just remove `test_data` the error does not occur. Thus, for some strange reason, TensorFlow-GPU 1.4.1 & CUDA 9 work with just a single `ConcurrentLoader`, but crash when multiple loaders are *initialized*.

Even more interesting is that (after the exception) I have to manually shut down the python processes, because the GPU's VRAM, the system's RAM and even the python processes stay alive after the script crashes.

Furthermore, it has to have some weird connection to Python's `multiprocessing` module, because when I implement the *same* model in Keras (using TF backend!) the code also runs just fine, with 2 concurrent loaders. I guess Keras is somehow creating an layer of abstraction in between that keeps TF from crashing.

Where could I possibly have screwed up with the `multiprocessing` module that it causes crashes like this one?

These are the parts of the code that use `multiprocessing` inside the `ConcurrentLoader`:

```
def __init__(self, dataset):
    ...
    self._q = mp.Queue(64)
    self._file_cycler = cycle(img_files)
    self._worker = mp.Process(target=self._worker_func, daemon=True)
    self._worker.start()

def _worker_func(self):
    while True:
        ... # gets next filepaths from self._file_cycler
        buffer = list()
        for im_path in paths:
            ... # uses OpenCV to load each image & puts it into the buffer
        self._q.put(np.array(buffer).astype(np.float32))
```

...and this is it.

Where have I written "unstable" or "non-pythonic" `multiprocessing` code? I thought `daemon=True` should ensure that every process gets killed as soon as the main process dies? Unfortunately, this is not the case for this specific error.

Did I misuse the default `multiprocessing.Process` or `multiprocessing.Queue` here? I thought simply writing a class where I store batches of images inside a Queue and make it accessible through methods / instance variables should be just fine.

Answer (score 1):

I am coming with the same error when trying to use tensorflow and multiprocessing

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_blas.cc:366] failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED
```

but in different environment tf1.4 + cuda 8.0 + cudnn 6.0.
matrixMulCUBLAS in sample codes works fine.
I wonder the correct solution too!
And the reference [failed to create cublas handle: CUBLAS_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED on a AWS p2.xlarge instance](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/5354) did not work for me.

Comment: After hours of testing I have experienced a very strange thing: if `tensorflow` is the last import and also initializing the session and so on happens last (after initializing data loaders and all other stuff) it works. At least for this specific DCGAN. This reminds me of the TensorFlow issue I created a while ago in GitHub: [segmentation fault with tensorflow 0.8.0 and matplotlib #2085](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/2085). This was also a bug inside of TensorFlow: worked fine if TF was imported last, gave a segfault if TF was imported first (with other libs like matplotlib)

Comment: Can you try if your error also disappears if you switch the order of imports (move TF down) and enable the session and stuff as late as possible?

Comment: Still failed into the same problem.
Actually, I am trying to train a multi-agent system (each agent has a network).  And to get low-correlation batch data, I use multi-work (multiprocessing) to collect data. However, it stuck here for a whole day..

Comment: @daniel451 :  I am having a similar kind of problem can you take look ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54402154/how-to-achieve-gpu-parallelism-using-tensor-flow